# Vertical align table-cell don't work with position absolute

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

http://jsfiddle.net/fQv97/

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-cell">
    My text, should be align middle
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table-cell {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #eee;
    display: table-cell;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**Problem**

The text should be placed in the middle of my "table cell". Everything works as expected until I add "position: absolute". Now it can't place my content in the middle any more? Why not? It still knows my height and width because I set it in my CSS.

Any clever workaround for this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Everything works as expected until I add "position: absolute". Now it
>   can't place my content in the middle any more? Why not?

`position: absolute` forces `display: block`, read number two [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo).

As for a workaround, I think you'll have to wrap it in another element:

```
<div class="table-cell-wrapper">
    <div class="table-cell">
        My text, should be align middle
    </div>
</div>

.table-cell-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
}
.table-cell {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #eee;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: I had to set my wrapper div to display: table to get this to work

Comment: tks, it helps me a lot

Answer (score 3):

There are some workarounds I've discovered for this, such as adding a hash before position:

```
#position: absolute;
```

That hack was found here: [Vertical Centering in CSS](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html)

Answer (score 3):

here is the solution:

```
<div style="position: absolute; /*your position*/">
    <div class="table-cell">
        My text, should be align middle
    </div>
</div>
```