# Vertical Align with Absolute Positioning

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

In the following code I'm trying to make the elements within the green div.middle elements to vertically align to the middle.

---

I've tried the table-cell approach but cant get it working. I heard it's due to absolute positioning and tried this solution with no luck:
[CSS - Vertical align table-cell don't work with position absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896965/css-vertical-align-table-cell-dont-work-with-position-absolute)

This appears to be due to .table-cell having no height - I would like it's height to equal its parent container, which varies in height.

---

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/q5jKM/1/

---

Does anyone know a way of getting the green div.middle elements to vertically align to the middle? Any method will do. It just needs to be capable of handling its variable height. Is it possible with just css? Or will I have to jump in with a bit of jQuery?

---

Edit:

box-align also isn't a viable solution due to browser support and being replaced with new standard.

---

CSS

```
     html,body{height:100%;margin:0}
#sidebar {
    width: 22em;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:2;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #333333;  
    overflow:auto;
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar .nav {
    width: 3em;
    float: right;
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    border-left: 2px groove #454545;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    min-height:34em;    
}

#sidebar .content {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 16.875em; /*    17-(2/16)   - 20em - .nav - nav border*/
    float:left; 
    position:relative;
    min-height:34em;
}

#sidebar .top {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
#sidebar .bottom {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}

#sidebar .middle {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 12em;       /*  3.125*3  */
    top: 16em;          /*  3.125*4  */
    background: green;
}

.content .middle {
    overflow:auto;
}


#sidebar .content > div {width: 16.875em; } /*.top .middle .bottom*/
#sidebar .nav > div {width:3em; } /*.top .middle .bottom*/


    /*table-cell trying get vertical-align working*/
#sidebar .table-cell {display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }



#sidebar .content p, #sidebar .content li, #sidebar .content img {font-size: .75em; color: #dddddd;}

#sidebar ul {margin:0; padding: 0;}









#sidebar .nav li {
    padding: .5625em;
    list-style:none;
}
#sidebar .nav li img {
    height: 1.875em;
    width: 1.875em
}

#sidebar .nav .top li { border-bottom: 2px groove #454545 }
#sidebar .nav .bottom li { border-top:  2px groove #454545 }




.content li {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    background-color: #444;
    padding: .72em;
    border-radius: .8em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #292929;
    border-top: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 1.2em;
}

.content li:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    display:block; 
    width:0;
    top:.11em; /* controls vertical position */
    right:-.852em; /* value = - border-left-width - border-right-width */
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1.2em 0 1.2em 1.2em;
    border-color:transparent #444;
}

.content .top li{margin: .95em 0 1.9em 0;}
.content .bottom li{margin: 1.9em 0 .95em 0;}

.content .logo {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em 0 2em 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px groove #454545;
}
.content p.welcome {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="sidebar">


            <div class="nav">
            <div class="top">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="_images/attributes/attribute2.svg"></li>
                <li><img src="_images/attributes/attribute2.svg"></li>
                <li><img src="_images/attributes/attribute2.svg"></li>
                <li><img src="_images/attributes/attribute2.svg"></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="middle"><div class="table-cell"><p>test</p></div></div>
            <div class="bottom">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="_images/attributes/attribute2.svg"></li>
                <li><img src="_images/attributes/attribute2.svg"></li>
                <li><img src="_images/attributes/attribute2.svg"></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>



            <div class="content">
                <div class="top">
                <ul>
                    <li>SIDEBAR LINK</li>
                    <li>SIDEBAR LINK</li>
                    <li>SIDEBAR LINK</li>
                    <li>SIDEBAR LINK</li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="middle"><div class="table-cell">
                <div class="logo"><img src="_images/g.svg"></div>
                <p class="welcome">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris dictum tellus viverra neque bibendum in mattis ante dignissim. Nam mattis feugiat lorem porttitor adipiscing. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc feugiat magna vitae mauris egestas euismod. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent magna sem, malesuada non fermentum vel, luctus quis mauris. Duis quam purus, ornare vitae eleifend sed, malesuada eget libero. Phasellus sed lorem risus, nec placerat urna. In magna turpis, accumsan ac egestas quis, dictum vel massa. Nulla vitae magna arcu. Maecenas sit amet vestibulum urna. Integer feugiat dignissim leo sed ornare. Maecenas auctor ultricies dui, pulvinar tincidunt velit feugiat quis. Sed egestas ornare elit, et fringilla quam viverra ut.</p>
                </div></div>
                <div class="bottom">
                <ul>
                    <li>SIDEBAR LINK</li>
                    <li>SIDEBAR LINK</li>
                    <li>SIDEBAR LINK</li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add a parent div with  `display:table` and `height:100%` to `.table-cell` will fix this

So the html structure wil be :

```
   <div class="middle">
        <div class="table">
           <div class="table-cell">
               <p>test</p>
           </div>
        </div>    
  </div>
```

add this Style:

```
#sidebar .table{
   display:table;
   height:100%;
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5jKM/7/) I have modified

Answer (score 2):

You can set a height for that table-cell.

```
.table-cell{
height: 200px;/* for example */
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;}

<div class="middle"><div class="table-cell"><p>test</p></div></div>
```

Comment: Hmm... this cell is variable in height - is the a way to get it to expand to the full height of it's container?

Answer (score 1):

I used to have problems with vertical-align property before. I tend to realize that this property seemed to be more suited for tables. So I added this in your code on JSFiddle and it looked alright to me. Could you see if this would work with you?

```
            <div class="middle">
                <table height="100%" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle">
                            <p>test</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks this works pretty well but I think I'll award the answer to aju as their code matches what I already have better. Thanks!