# vertical align to absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tCWr2/)

```
div{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*position: absolute;*/
}
```

In the above demo If you remove the comment from `position: absolute;` the vertical-align won't work.

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472794/vertical-align-with-absolute-positioning) but here is added a parent div. But in my case, I need without touching up markup. Any idea?

Comment: position absolute and position fixed dont work with display table cell

Answer (score 0):

here is the refrence for ur detail 
position: absolute forces display: block, read number two [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo).

As for a workaround, I think you'll have to wrap it in another element:

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle as a workaround..http://jsfiddle.net/DjGQ5/
Change `display : block` and Wrapped text in p tag with padding-top: 50% property in css

Answer (score 0):

Wow! I did it. See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tCWr2/2/)

```
div{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
}
div:before{content: " "; height: 50%; display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: if i used to multiple line than result is this http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/tCWr2/3/

Comment: ur just pushing it by before property add more text it wont center

Comment: anyway, in my case this will be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Jus make `Position:relative` Its fine now... Updated the fiddle.. Here is the link..

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tCWr2/4/)

Comment: You didn't notice to the question? It's about absolute position.

Comment: I don't need display table cell but position absolute and vertical-align to middle... any idea....

Comment: No buddy.. I tried all the combinations possible.. But I wasnt able to achieve it... Sorry.. :(