# Vertically align text middle in div element CSS

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically align the text in my banner I've coded but can't seem to work out how to get the display:table-cell; and vertical-align:middle; to work.

Below is the code I have used along with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huddds/v7dBm/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
    <div>
        <img src="#" alt="Image 1" width="650" height="326" class="bannerImg item1 selectedImg" />
        <img src="#" alt="Image 2" width="650" height="326" class="bannerImg item2" />
        <img src="#" alt="Image 3" width="650" height="326" class="bannerImg item3" />
    </div>
    <div class="bannerTags">

        <div class="tagItem tag1 selectedTag">
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tagItem tag2">
            <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tagItem tag3">
            <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner{width:650px; height:326px; background-color:#000000; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}
.bannerTags{text-align:center; width:650px; height:80px; position:absolute; bottom:0px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0.7))); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.7));}
.tagItem{width:217px; height:80px; float:left; position:relative;display:inline-block}
.tagItem a{position:absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 80px; vertical-align: middle; right: 0px;bottom: 0px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration:none;}
.selectedTag{width:216px !important; height:80px; background-color:#d7df23;}
.selectedTag a{color:#000000 !important; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}
.bannerImg{display:none;}
.selectImg{display:block;}  
.clr{clear:both;}
.bannerArrow{width: 0px; height: 0px; border-style: solid; border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px; border-color: transparent transparent #d7df23 transparent; position:absolute; bottom:80px; left:108px; margin-left:-10px;}
```

jQuery:

```
var bannerPause = 0;
var bannerValue = 1;
var tagValue = 1;
var hoveredTag;

$('.item1').show();
$('.selectedTag').append('<div class="bannerArrow"></div>');

setInterval(function(){
    if(bannerPause == 0){
        $('.bannerArrow').remove();
        $('.tagItem').removeClass('selectedTag');
        if(bannerValue == 3){
            bannerValue = 1;
            tagValue = 1
        }else{
            bannerValue += 1;
            tagValue += 1;
        }
        $('.bannerImg').hide();
        $('.item'+bannerValue).show();
        $('.tag'+tagValue).addClass('selectedTag');
        $('.selectedTag').append('<div class="bannerArrow"></div>');
    }else{}
},5000);


$('.tag1').mouseenter(function(){   
    bannerValue = 1;
    tagValue = 1;
    $('.bannerArrow').remove();
    $('.tagItem').removeClass('selectedTag');
    $('.bannerImg').hide();
    $('.item'+bannerValue).show();
    $('.tag'+tagValue).addClass('selectedTag');
    $('.selectedTag').append('<div class="bannerArrow"></div>');
})

$('.tag2').mouseenter(function(){   
    bannerValue = 2;
    tagValue = 2;
    $('.bannerArrow').remove();
    $('.tagItem').removeClass('selectedTag');
    $('.bannerImg').hide();
    $('.item'+bannerValue).show();
    $('.tag'+tagValue).addClass('selectedTag');
    $('.selectedTag').append('<div class="bannerArrow"></div>');
})

$('.tag3').mouseenter(function(){   
    bannerValue = 3;
    tagValue = 3;
    $('.bannerArrow').remove();
    $('.tagItem').removeClass('selectedTag');
    $('.bannerImg').hide();
    $('.item'+bannerValue).show();
    $('.tag'+tagValue).addClass('selectedTag');
    $('.selectedTag').append('<div class="bannerArrow"></div>');
})

$('.tagItem').mouseenter(function(){   
    bannerPause = 1;
})
$('.tagItem').mouseleave(function(){
    bannerPause = 0;
})
```

Comment: Have a look at this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/v7dBm/3/) and see if it helps. I just added `top: 40%;` to  `.tagItem a`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - Vertical align table-cell don't work with position absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896965/css-vertical-align-table-cell-dont-work-with-position-absolute)

Comment: This won't work as sometimes this will be 2 lines. Thanks anyway

Comment: `.tagItem a { line-height: 5; }` or top and bottom padding, works also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
.tagItem {display: table;}

.tagItem a{height: 80px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}
```

.tagItem a without position:absolute;

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
.tagItem a{
    position:absolute; 
    top: 35%; 
    left: 0px; 
    height: 80px; 
    right: 0px; 
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: I have formatted the code and split them into multiple lines. Hope you have no issues with it.