# fix vertical align in table cell with position:absolute

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Need create table with fixed column. When set absolute position then cell with 'text1' don't have center vertical align. How to correct?

```html
<style>
.th {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; width: 300px;
}
.tbl{ margin-left: 305px;}
td{height:100px;width:200px; vertical-align: middle; text-align:center;}
</style>

<table class=tbl border=1 >
 <tr >
  <td class=th>text1</td>
  <td>text2</td>
  <td>text3</td>
  <td>text4</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: give .th a height

Comment: Not sure what's going on with the `position: absolute` but you can add a `line-height` to vertically center the text within the table cell. Note: This is not the best or the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertical align table-cell don't work with position absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896965/vertical-align-table-cell-dont-work-with-position-absolute)

Comment: Since it is not part of your table-layout anymore, you can relay on flex or grid. flex example: `.th {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set for cell with 'text1' only absolute position
and in inner div set again display: table-cell and vertical-align:middle

```html
<style>
.th{position:absolute;border:none}
.th2 {
   height:100px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:green;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    left:-200px;
    position:relative;
}
.tbl{ margin-left: 305px;}
td{height:100px;width:200px;vertical-align:bottom; }
</style>

<table class=tbl border=3 >
 <tr >
  <td class=th> <div class=th2>text1</div></td>
  <td>text2</td>
  <td>text3</td>
  <td>text4</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```